# Adding this project will cause a circular dependency

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

I have a WPF application composed by two assemblies.

Assembly A is a wpf application.

Assembly B is a 3D app whit a public API mainly used by A.

Assembly A has a reference to assembly B.

Now when an event fires on assembly B I need to call a method in assembly A  in a static class app.

If I try to add a reference to assembly A in B I get an error:

> adding this project will cause a circular dependency

Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

Specifically I would like to know:

- How to call `App.myMethod()` in A from `assembly B`?
- In order to decouple the classes, could I fire a generic event on assembly B and catch it on assembly A?
- Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: How is the event created? Can you pass the `static class` into your event when you create it as part of initialization?

Comment: Inversion of control pattern is to design to deal wit this case.

Comment: I can change the source code for both assemblies. Right now the event handler from assembly B is         private void OnTouchDownHandler(object sender, Windows7.Multitouch.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            
            AddTouchDown(e.Id, e.Location);
        }

Comment: Could you move the static method either to B, or a third assembly that both A and B both reference?

Comment: Thanks juharr, interesting approach but I cannot move static B neither create a third assembly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I call `App.myMethod` in A from assembly B?

You can't if A depends on B.

If the event is *fired* from some class in B you should *subscribe* to that event from some class in A:

code in A:

```
var classB = new ClassB();  // presumably in your code in A somewhere
classB.MyEvent += new EventHandler(this.HandleEventFromB);


public void HandleEventFromB(object sneder, EventArgs args)
{
    ClassA.StaticMethod();
}
```

That way B is not dependent on A.

You may need to "bubble up" the event within B to some publicly exposed event in order to subscribe to it from A.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it if you add a reference to the built DLL, instead of the project.

Comment: You still have a circular dependency and would have to build each project separately.

Comment: The project can still be built at the same time in the same solution, it just cant be added as a project reference. It will work like this, its just not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a design issue. As i'm not aware of the specific details in your implementation take the following as a guideline/idea.

When the event fires on B I'm assuming it creates some data. If you could store this data in a database or similar and then have perhaps a timed event in application A that essentially listens for this data and then provides to update with it as necessary.